# How to apply piecewise linear fit in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, piecewise

I am trying to fit piecewise linear fit as shown in fig.1 for a data set

[image]

This figure was obtained by setting on the lines. I attempted to apply a piecewise linear fit using the code:

```
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
y = np.array([5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 28.92, 42.81, 56.7, 70.59, 84.47, 98.36, 112.25, 126.14, 140.03])


def linear_fit(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b
fit_a, fit_b = optimize.curve_fit(linear_fit, x[0:5], y[0:5])[0]
y_fit = fit_a * x[0:7] + fit_b
fit_a, fit_b = optimize.curve_fit(linear_fit, x[6:14], y[6:14])[0]
y_fit = np.append(y_fit, fit_a * x[6:14] + fit_b)


figure = plt.figure(figsize=(5.15, 5.15))
figure.clf()
plot = plt.subplot(111)
ax1 = plt.gca()
plot.plot(x, y, linestyle = '', linewidth = 0.25, markeredgecolor='none', marker = 'o', label = r'\textit{y_a}')
plot.plot(x, y_fit, linestyle = ':', linewidth = 0.25, markeredgecolor='none', marker = '', label = r'\textit{y_b}')
plot.set_ylabel('Y', labelpad = 6)
plot.set_xlabel('X', labelpad = 6)
figure.savefig('test.pdf', box_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

But this gave me fitting of the form in fig. 2, I tried playing with the values but no change I can't get the fit of the upper line proper. The most important requirement for me is how can I get Python to get the gradient change point.

I want the code to recognize and fit two linear fits in the appropriate range. How can this be done in Python?

[image]

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use `numpy.piecewise()` to create the piecewise function and then use `curve_fit()`, Here is the code

```
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,11, 12, 13, 14, 15], dtype=float)
y = np.array([5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 28.92, 42.81, 56.7, 70.59, 84.47, 98.36, 112.25, 126.14, 140.03])

def piecewise_linear(x, x0, y0, k1, k2):
    return np.piecewise(x, [x < x0], [lambda x:k1*x + y0-k1*x0, lambda x:k2*x + y0-k2*x0])

p , e = optimize.curve_fit(piecewise_linear, x, y)
xd = np.linspace(0, 15, 100)
plt.plot(x, y, "o")
plt.plot(xd, piecewise_linear(xd, *p))
```

the output:

[image]

For an N parts fitting, please reference [segments_fit.ipynb](https://gist.github.com/ruoyu0088/70effade57483355bbd18b31dc370f2a)

Comment: How do I extend this to three parts?

Comment: Since I was interested in the errors,  I generated some noisy points with : `x = np.random.normal(7,5,15)` and `y= piecewise_linear(x, 5.5,10,0.5,10) +np.random.normal(0,3,x.size)`   The end points of the sample have a lot of leverage on the slopes.

Comment: Since the initial guess of the parameters is `[1,1,1,1]` with other data it might not converge into a good fit -- it will look for local optimums near a linear fit through (1,1)   Maybe consider a more sane initial point like `p , e = optimize.curve_fit(piecewise_linear, x, y,p0=[x.mean(), y.mean(),0,0])`

Answer (score 35):

You can use [pwlf](https://github.com/cjekel/piecewise_linear_fit_py) to perform continuous piecewise linear regression in Python. This library can be installed [using pip](https://pypi.org/project/pwlf/).

There are two approaches in pwlf to perform your fit:

1. You can fit for a specified number of line segments.
2. You can specify the x locations where the continuous piecewise lines should terminate.

Let's go with approach 1 since it's easier, and will recognize the 'gradient change point' that you are interested in.

I notice two distinct regions when looking at the data. Thus it makes sense to find the best possible continuous piecewise line using two line segments. This is approach 1.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pwlf

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
y = np.array([5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 28.92, 42.81, 56.7, 70.59,
              84.47, 98.36, 112.25, 126.14, 140.03])

my_pwlf = pwlf.PiecewiseLinFit(x, y)
breaks = my_pwlf.fit(2)
print(breaks)
```

[ 1.          5.99819559 15.        ]

The first line segment runs from [1., 5.99819559], while the second line segment runs from [5.99819559, 15.]. Thus the gradient change point you asked for would be 5.99819559.

We can plot these results using the predict function.

```
x_hat = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
y_hat = my_pwlf.predict(x_hat)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(x_hat, y_hat, '-')
plt.show()
```

[image: The resulting fit]

Answer (score 28):

You could do a [spline interpolation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation) scheme to both perform piecewise linear interpolation and find the turning point of the curve. The second derivative will be the highest at the turning point (for an monotonically increasing curve), and can be calculated with a spline interpolation of order > 2.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
y = np.array([5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 28.92, 42.81, 56.7, 70.59, 84.47, 98.36, 112.25, 126.14, 140.03])

tck = interpolate.splrep(x, y, k=2, s=0)
xnew = np.linspace(0, 15)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3)

axes[0].plot(x, y, 'x', label = 'data')
axes[0].plot(xnew, interpolate.splev(xnew, tck, der=0), label = 'Fit')
axes[1].plot(x, interpolate.splev(x, tck, der=1), label = '1st dev')
dev_2 = interpolate.splev(x, tck, der=2)
axes[2].plot(x, dev_2, label = '2st dev')

turning_point_mask = dev_2 == np.amax(dev_2)
axes[2].plot(x[turning_point_mask], dev_2[turning_point_mask],'rx',
             label = 'Turning point')
for ax in axes:
    ax.legend(loc = 'best')

plt.show()
```

[image: Turning point and piecewise linear interpolation]

Answer (score 13):

[image]

This approach uses `Scikit-Learn` to apply segmented linear regression.
You can use this, if your points are are subject to noise.
It is way **faster**, significantly more **robust** and more **generic** than performing a giant optimization task (anything from `scip.optimize` like `curve_fit` with more then 3 parameters).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# parameters for setup
n_data = 20

# segmented linear regression parameters
n_seg = 3

np.random.seed(0)
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

# example 1
#xs = np.sort(np.random.rand(n_data))
#ys = np.random.rand(n_data) * .3 + np.tanh(5* (xs -.5))

# example 2
xs = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)
ys = np.random.rand(n_data) * .3 + np.tanh(3*xs)

dys = np.gradient(ys, xs)

rgr = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_leaf_nodes=n_seg)
rgr.fit(xs.reshape(-1, 1), dys.reshape(-1, 1))
dys_dt = rgr.predict(xs.reshape(-1, 1)).flatten()

ys_sl = np.ones(len(xs)) * np.nan
for y in np.unique(dys_dt):
    msk = dys_dt == y
    lin_reg = LinearRegression()
    lin_reg.fit(xs[msk].reshape(-1, 1), ys[msk].reshape(-1, 1))
    ys_sl[msk] = lin_reg.predict(xs[msk].reshape(-1, 1)).flatten()
    ax0.plot([xs[msk][0], xs[msk][-1]],
             [ys_sl[msk][0], ys_sl[msk][-1]],
             color='r', zorder=1)

ax0.set_title('values')
ax0.scatter(xs, ys, label='data')
ax0.scatter(xs, ys_sl, s=3**2, label='seg lin reg', color='g', zorder=5)
ax0.legend()

ax1.set_title('slope')
ax1.scatter(xs, dys, label='data')
ax1.scatter(xs, dys_dt, label='DecisionTree', s=2**2)
ax1.legend()

plt.show()
```

### how it works

- calculate slope at each point
- group similar slopes by using a decision tree (right plot)
- perform linear regression for each group in the original data

Comment: This is a very good approach.  A couple modifications are required to get it to run.  1: Define `n_data` and `n_seg` (and use `n_data` to generate `xs`).  2: Probably best to specify the imports.

Comment: Is there a way to automize n_seg such that it divides the data into the amount of segments that most optimally seperates the data?

Comment: Is there a way to make it fit a piece-wise continuous linear model?

Answer (score 7):

An example for two change points. If you want, just test more change points based on this example.

```
np.random.seed(9999)
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000) * 10
y = np.where(x < -15, -2 * x + 3 , np.where(x < 10, x + 48, -4 * x + 98)) + np.random.normal(0, 3, 1000)
plt.scatter(x, y, s = 5, color = u'b', marker = '.', label = 'scatter plt')

def piecewise_linear(x, x0, x1, b, k1, k2, k3):
    condlist = [x < x0, (x >= x0) & (x < x1), x >= x1]
    funclist = [lambda x: k1*x + b, lambda x: k1*x + b + k2*(x-x0), lambda x: k1*x + b + k2*(x-x0) + k3*(x - x1)]
    return np.piecewise(x, condlist, funclist)

p , e = optimize.curve_fit(piecewise_linear, x, y)
xd = np.linspace(-30, 30, 1000)
plt.plot(x, y, "o")
plt.plot(xd, piecewise_linear(xd, *p))
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for **Linear Trees**. They are the best method to apply, in a generalized and automated way, a piecewise linear fit (also for multivariate and in classification contexts).

**Linear Trees** differ from **Decision Trees** because they compute linear approximation (instead of constant ones) fitting simple Linear Models in the leaves.

For a project of mine, I developed [linear-tree](https://github.com/cerlymarco/linear-tree): *a python library to build Model Trees with Linear Models at the leaves.*

[image]

linear-tree is developed to be fully integrable with scikit-learn.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import *
from lineartree import LinearTreeRegressor, LinearTreeClassifier

# REGRESSION
regr = LinearTreeRegressor(base_estimator=LinearRegression())
regr.fit(X, y)

# CLASSIFICATION
clf = LinearTreeClassifier(base_estimator=RidgeClassifier())
clf.fit(X, y)
```

`LinearTreeRegressor` and `LinearTreeClassifier` are provided as scikit-learn `BaseEstimator`. They are wrappers that build a decision tree on the data fitting a linear estimator from `sklearn.linear_model`. All the models available in `sklearn.linear_model` can be used as linear estimators.

Compare Decision Tree with Linear Tree:

[image]

[image]

Considering your data, the generalization is extremely straightforward:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from lineartree import LinearTreeRegressor
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
    ).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.array(
    [5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 28.92, 42.81, 56.7, 70.59, 84.47, 98.36, 112.25, 126.14, 140.03]
    )

model = LinearTreeRegressor(base_estimator=LinearRegression())
model.fit(X, y)

plt.plot(X, y, ".", label='TRUE')
plt.plot(X, model.predict(X), label='PRED')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `piecewise-regression` [python package](https://joss.theoj.org/papers/10.21105/joss.03859) handles exactly this problem.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import piecewise_regression

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
y = np.array([5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 28.92, 42.81, 56.7, 70.59, 84.47, 98.36, 112.25, 126.14, 140.03])

pw_fit = piecewise_regression.Fit(x, y, n_breakpoints=1)
pw_fit.plot()
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

[image: piecewise-regression fit]

It also gives the results of the fit:

```
pw_fit.summary()
```

[image: Statistical summary of the fit]

It works by implementing Muggeo's iterative algorithm. [More code examples here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Pwv6LqwZU8Zbl0VZH6cwOTwoRzm3CPPC#offline=true&sandboxMode=true/)

**Example with some noise**. For a more interesting example, we can add some noise to the y data and fit it again:

```
y += np.random.normal(size=len(y)) * 5

pw_fit = piecewise_regression.Fit(x, y, n_breakpoints=1)
pw_fit.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/chasmani/piecewise-regression  is cool.  It would be interesting to see the summary for the data+noise example.

Answer (score 3):

Use `numpy.interp` which returns the one-dimensional piecewise linear interpolant to a function with given values at discrete data-points.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the essence question "I want Python to recognize and fit two linear fits in the appropriate range. How can this be done in Python?" `numpy.interp` only connects the dots, but it does not apply a fit. The result happens to be the same for the presented example, but that's not true in general.

Answer (score 2):

I think that `UnivariateSpline` from [scipy.interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html) would provide the simplest and very likely the fastest way to do piecewise fit. To add a bit of context, spline is a function defined piecewise by polynomials. In your case, you are looking for a linear spline which is defined by `k=1` in `UnivariateSpline`. Also, `s=0.5` is a smoothing factor which indicates how good the fit should be (check out the documentation for more info on it).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
y = np.array([5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 28.92, 42.81, 56.7, 70.59, 84.47, 98.36, 112.25, 126.14, 140.03])


# Solution
spl = UnivariateSpline(x, y, k=1, s=0.5)
xs = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 1000)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, color="red", s=20, zorder=20)
ax.plot(xs, spl(xs), linestyle="--", linewidth=1, color="blue", zorder=10)
ax.grid(color="grey", linestyle="--", linewidth=.5, alpha=.5)
ax.set_ylabel("Y")
ax.set_xlabel("X")
plt.show()
```

[image: Fitting UnivariateSpline]

Answer (score 2):

There are already good answers here, but here's another way to do it using a simple neural network. The basic idea is the same as some of the other answers; i.e.,

- create dummy variables that indicate whether the input variable is greater than some break point
- create dummy interactions by subtracting the break point from the input variable and then multiplying the result with the corresponding dummy variable
- train a linear model using the input variable and dummy interactions as features

The main difference is that here the break points are learned end-to-end via gradient descent rather than treated as hyperparameters. This approach naturally extends to more than one break point and can be used with any relevant loss function.

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
y = np.array([5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 28.92, 42.81, 56.7, 70.59,
              84.47, 98.36, 112.25, 126.14, 140.03])
```

Define the model, optimizer, and loss function:

```
class PiecewiseLinearModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_breaks):
        super(PiecewiseLinearModel, self).__init__()
        self.breaks = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.randn((1,n_breaks)))
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(n_breaks+1, 1)        
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(torch.cat([x, torch.clamp_min(x - self.breaks, 0)],1))

plm = PiecewiseLinearModel(n_breaks=1)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(plm.parameters(), lr=0.1)
loss_func = torch.nn.functional.mse_loss
```

Train the model:

```
x_torch = torch.tensor(x, dtype=torch.float)[:,None]
y_torch = torch.tensor(y)[:,None]
for _ in range(10000):
    p = plm(x_torch)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss_func(y_torch, p).backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Plot the predictions:

```
x_grid = np.linspace(0,16,1000)
p = plm(torch.tensor(x_grid, dtype=torch.float)[:,None])
p = p.flatten().detach().numpy()
plt.plot(x, y, ".")
plt.plot(x_grid, p)
plt.show()
```

[image: toy piecewise linear model]

Inspect the model parameters:

```
print(plm.state_dict())
> OrderedDict([('breaks', tensor([[6.0033]])),
               ('linear.weight', tensor([[ 1.9999, 11.8892]])),
               ('linear.bias', tensor([2.9963]))])
```

The predictions of neural network are equivalent to:

```
def f(x): 
   return 1.9999*x + 11.8892*(x - 6.0033)*(x > 6.0033) + 2.9963
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending @binoy-pilakkat's answer.

You should use `numpy.interp`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array(range(1,16), dtype=float)
y = np.array([5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 28.92,
          42.81, 56.7, 70.59, 84.47,
          98.36, 112.25, 126.14, 140.03], dtype=float)

yinterp = np.interp(x, x, y) # simple as that

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
plt.plot(x, yinterp, 'g-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This answer doesn't address the essence question "I want Python to recognize and fit two linear fits in the appropriate range. How can this be done in Python?" numpy.interp only connects the dots, but it does not apply a fit. The result happens to be the same for the presented example, but that's not true in general.

Answer (score 1):

[piecewise](https://github.com/DataDog/piecewise) works too

```
from piecewise.regressor import piecewise
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,11, 12, 13, 14, 15,16,17,18], dtype=float)
y = np.array([5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 28.92, 42.81, 56.7, 70.59, 84.47, 98.36, 112.25, 126.14, 140.03,120,112,110])

model = piecewise(x, y)
```

Evaluate 'model':

```
FittedModel with segments:
* FittedSegment(start_t=1.0, end_t=7.0, coeffs=(2.9999999999999996, 2.0000000000000004))
* FittedSegment(start_t=7.0, end_t=16.0, coeffs=(-68.2972222222222, 13.888333333333332))
* FittedSegment(start_t=16.0, end_t=18.0, coeffs=(198.99999999999997, -5.000000000000001))
```