# Piecewise linear fit with n breakpoints

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, piecewise

I have used some code found in the question [How to apply piecewise linear fit in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382903/how-to-apply-piecewise-linear-fit-in-python), to perform segmented linear approximation with a single breakpoint.

The code is as follows:

```
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,11, 12, 13, 14, 15], dtype=float)
y = np.array([5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 28.92, 42.81, 56.7, 70.59, 84.47, 98.36, 112.25, 126.14, 140.03])

def piecewise_linear(x, x0, y0, k1, k2):
    return np.piecewise(x, 
                       [x < x0], 
                       [lambda x:k1*x + y0-k1*x0, lambda x:k2*x + y0-k2*x0])

p , e = optimize.curve_fit(piecewise_linear, x, y)
xd = np.linspace(0, 15, 100)
plt.plot(x, y, "o")
plt.plot(xd, piecewise_linear(xd, *p))
```

I am trying to figure out how I can extend this to handle n breakpoints.

I tried the following code for the piecewise_linear() method to handle 2 breakpoints, but it does not alter the values of the breakpoints in any way.

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], dtype=float)
y = np.array([5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 28.92, 42.81, 56.7, 70.59, 84.47, 98.36, 112.25, 126.14, 140.03, 150, 152, 154, 156, 158])

def piecewise_linear(x, x0, x1, a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3):
    return np.piecewise(x,
                       [x < x0, np.logical_and(x >= x0, x < x1), x >= x1 ], 
                       [lambda x:a1*x + b1, lambda x:a2*x+b2, lambda x: a3*x + b3])

p , e = optimize.curve_fit(piecewise_linear, x, y)
xd = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
plt.plot(x, y, "o")
plt.plot(xd, piecewise_linear(xd, *p))
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated

Comment: ```It does not work``` is a pretty much useless description. I also think you won't achieve that with curve_fit(), which gets more complex when there are multiple breakpoints (would need linear-constraints to handle b0 < b1; not supported; ignoring this and sorting before np.piecewise touches the last argument here). It's also a non-convex optimization problem and therefore all those optimizers available in scipy only achieve a local-minimum (if they achieve that at all). That being said, i also doubt the effectiveness of the one-breakpoint approach using curve-fit (as it's non-smooth).

Comment: I think that if I initially distribute the breakpoints uniformly across the x-axis then finding local-minimums will be sufficient to provide a decent non-optimal solution. Do you know of another optimization module which does support linear constraints?

Comment: As i told you, it's not just about that. Ignoring smoothness and potential non-convexity, you can solve this problem with scipy's more general optimize functions, namely COBYLA and SQSLP (the only two supporting constraints). The only real approach i see would be mixed-integer convex-programming, but software is sparse (bonmin and couenne being two open-source solvers not that nice to use from python; pajarito @ julialang; but this approach in general needs some non-trivial formulation).

Answer (score 7):

NumPy has a [`polyfit` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html) which makes it very easy to find the best fit line through a set of points:

```
coefs = npoly.polyfit(xi, yi, 1)
```

So really the only difficulty is finding the breakpoints. For a given set of
breakpoints it's trivial to find the best fit lines through the given data.

So instead of trying to find location of the breakpoints *and* the coefficients
of the linear parts all at once, it suffices to minimize over a parameter space
of breakpoints.

Since the breakpoints can be specified by their integer index values into the `x` array,
the parameter space can be thought of as points on an integer grid of `N` dimensions, where 
`N` is the number of breakpoints.

`optimize.curve_fit` is not a good choice as the minimizer for this problem
because the parameter space is integer-valued. If you were to use `curve_fit`,
the algorithm would tweak the parameters to determine in which direction to
move. If the tweak is less than 1 unit, the x-values of the breakpoints do not
change, so the error does not change, so the algorithm gains no information
about the correct direction in which to shift the parameters. Hence `curve_fit`
tends to fail when the parameter space is essentially integer-valued.

A better, but not very fast, minimizer would be a brute-force grid search.  If
the number of breakpoints is small (and the parameter space of `x`-values is
small) this might suffice. If the number of breakpoints is large and/or the
parameter space is large, then perhaps set up a multi-stage coarse/fine
(brute-force) grid search. Or, perhaps someone will suggest a smarter minimizer than brute-force...

---

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as npoly
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(2017)

def f(breakpoints, x, y, fcache):
    breakpoints = tuple(map(int, sorted(breakpoints)))
    if breakpoints not in fcache:
        total_error = 0
        for f, xi, yi in find_best_piecewise_polynomial(breakpoints, x, y):
            total_error += ((f(xi) - yi)**2).sum()
        fcache[breakpoints] = total_error
    # print('{} --> {}'.format(breakpoints, fcache[breakpoints]))
    return fcache[breakpoints]

def find_best_piecewise_polynomial(breakpoints, x, y):
    breakpoints = tuple(map(int, sorted(breakpoints)))
    xs = np.split(x, breakpoints)
    ys = np.split(y, breakpoints)
    result = []
    for xi, yi in zip(xs, ys):
        if len(xi) < 2: continue
        coefs = npoly.polyfit(xi, yi, 1)
        f = npoly.Polynomial(coefs)
        result.append([f, xi, yi])
    return result

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
              18, 19, 20], dtype=float)
y = np.array([5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 28.92, 42.81, 56.7, 70.59, 84.47, 98.36, 112.25, 
              126.14, 140.03, 150, 152, 154, 156, 158])
# Add some noise to make it exciting :)
y += np.random.random(len(y))*10

num_breakpoints = 2
breakpoints = optimize.brute(
    f, [slice(1, len(x), 1)]*num_breakpoints, args=(x, y, {}), finish=None)

plt.scatter(x, y, c='blue', s=50)
for f, xi, yi in find_best_piecewise_polynomial(breakpoints, x, y):
    x_interval = np.array([xi.min(), xi.max()])
    print('y = {:35s}, if x in [{}, {}]'.format(str(f), *x_interval))
    plt.plot(x_interval, f(x_interval), 'ro-')


plt.show()
```

prints

```
y = poly([ 4.58801083  2.94476604])    , if x in [1.0, 6.0]
y = poly([-70.36472935  14.37305793])  , if x in [7.0, 15.0]
y = poly([ 123.24565235    1.94982153]), if x in [16.0, 20.0]
```

and plots

[image]

Comment: Great answer... I tried everything I could with `leastsq` and `minimize` but the piecewise parameters `x0` and `x1` are just not optimized correctly

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: How would one change this to allow for curve_fit to work (and assuming the data is not strictly integer-spaced)?

Comment: Also, what is `fcache` representing here?

Comment: @genjong: `fcache` is a [memoizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). It is a dict which maps pairs of breakpoints to the corresponding total error. `f` can be called more than once with the same breakpoints. `fcache` makes `f` more efficient by simply returning the memoized total error instead of computing the same thing twice. You can see it in action by uncommenting the `print` statement in `f`.

Comment: @genjong: To apply `curve_fit`, you would first need to define a function similar to `f` which maps continuous-valued breakpoints to a measure of `total_error`. Once you have such an `f`, applying `curve_fit` is in theory straight-forward, [just like any other application of `curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).

Comment: Note that successful use of `curve_fit` generally requires `f` to be reasonably smooth but also have enough variation to allow the gradient to point in the direction of the minimum.
If you modify `f` to simply "snap" continuous-valued breakpoints to the nearest integer, then `f` will be locally flat, so the optimizer will not be able to find a minimum because the gradient will be zero in all directions.