# python piecewise constant approximation

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

Assume the time series `X_t` is given. Is there any already implemented `python` function for finding best piecewise constant (not linear in general) approximation for it? Ideally dependent on the number of breaks.

UPD Once again, it differs from [How to apply piecewise linear fit in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382903/how-to-apply-piecewise-linear-fit-in-python), because I need **specifically** constant piecewise approximation (curve fit!) with `k=0` with given number of breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Would [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) from numpy work?

You can do something like,

```
x = np.linspace(-2.5, 2.5, 6)
np.piecewise(x, [x < 0, x >= 0], [-1, 1])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, this is piecewise implementation, but I'm talking about **curve fitting** with piecewise constant with `n` breaks