# Are there any Python options for 3D linear piecewise/segmented regression

Tags: python, piecewise

I'm looking for a solution to fit a number of piecewise planes to linearly approximate a surface. Ideally the user could define the number of planes and the code would determine the "optimal" pieces of the data to fit them to.

There seems to be a number of 2D options discussed, e.g., here [How to apply piecewise linear fit in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382903/how-to-apply-piecewise-linear-fit-in-python) but nothing in 3D.

Thanks!