# Extracting the linear part of a curve in python

Tags: python, math, scipy, linear-regression, linear-algebra

I have two array and after plotting the line graph with respect to x-axis and y-axis, I want to extract the linear part of graph in python. How can i do that with precision?   For example:
x-axis = [1,2,3,4] (Time in seconds) and y-axis = [values]. So, just want to calculate the slope and intercept of the linear part.

I tried using linregress function from scipy but the results weren't accurate enough. Is there any other function I can use.

[For example, this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jOSl.png)

[Now I want just this part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO48h.png)

Comment: you mean a linear regression? check the definition, and if that is what you meant there are plenty of libs that do that..

Comment: What do you mean 'linear part'? Do you mean derivative?

Comment: No, not linear regression. i updated the post and explained it in the photo.

Comment: So you need to say at which x value you want the slope and intercept. How is anyone supposed to know you didn't want the slope and intercept of the first flat part in your example?

Comment: i want the slope and intercept of longest straight line which is there in the graph and it doesn't depend on values of x-axis. Maybe I am not explaining properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply piecewise linear fit in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382903/how-to-apply-piecewise-linear-fit-in-python)

Comment: No, it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

polyfit function to fit a polynomial to your data. You'll need to specify the degree of the polynomial (in this case, 1 for a linear fit), as well as your x and y data:

```
slope, intercept = np.polyfit(x_axis, y_axis, 1)
```

Comment: I tried but it doesnt give the accurate answer.