# python - Is there a way to interpolate a spline with a predefined number of knots?

Tags: python, scipy, spline

What I am trying to do basically is translate this Matlab line:

```matlab
slm = slmengine(x,y,'degree',1,'knots',numOfKnots,'plot','off');
```

to python.

So far I've found [make_inter_spline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline.html#scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline) which doesn't let me control how many knots there are, and [make_lsq_spline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.make_lsq_spline.html#scipy.interpolate.make_lsq_spline) which makes me calculate the knots before hand.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Are you trying to perform a piecewise linear fit like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382903/how-to-apply-piecewise-linear-fit-in-python?

Comment: @jared I am trying to fit a linear piecewise spline with less knots that data points

Comment: So, does that link answer your question? You obviously would need to adjust it to fit your need of specifying the number of  knots/bends.

Comment: `pwlf` is doing what I am trying to do, but it is very slow. I have several thousand blobs, each containing hundreds of points.

Comment: Can you provide a representative example to test on?

Comment: I am trying to fit a 20-knot spline for every connected component in a binary image, for several thresholds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [this package called `pwlf`](https://github.com/cjekel/piecewise_linear_fit_py) that solves the problem, even though it is very slow compared to anything from SciPy. To use it you can simply do

```py
spline = pwlf.PiecewiseLinFit(x, y)
spline.fitfast(num_of_knots)
y_hat = spline.predict(x)
```

which was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using scipy.interpolate.LSQUnivariateSpline (in at least 1.8.1). As noted in the documentation:

> class scipy.interpolate.LSQUnivariateSpline(x, y, t, w=None, bbox=[None, None], k=3, ext=0,
> check_finite=False)

> 1-D spline with explicit internal knots.

> Fits a spline y = spl(x) of degree k to the provided x, y data. t specifies the internal knots of the spline

Comment: But you must provide the knots before hand

Comment: Well, either you know enough about what the spline is being fit to so you can provide reasonable knots, or you are asking the impossible. How much do you know about the points you are trying to run a spline through?

Comment: I know the points should (but not always) be in a straight line, and that the spline should be in the middle of the blob of points