# Plotting two lines of best fit, and finding intersection point, on a 'dogleg' plot uisng Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, lmplot, regplot

I am trying to fit two lines of best fit on this plot, and to find the intersection point of these lines. This will be used in conjunction with a `seaborn.facetgrid` to show a trend across years.

[image: Dogleg plot to fit two LOBF on - one following steep decline, one showing the start of a plateau]

I have used `sns.lmplot`, and `sns.regplot`, each delivering 1 line of best fit. I have used `regplot` alongside the inbuilt 'hue' function, with manually chosen data points to generate two lines of best fit - but I was wondering if this can be automated and therefore, not reliant on human selection of datapoints.

This was created using `sns.regplot`, with hue deciding the colouring of datapoints at the LOBF plotted based on colour:

[image: This was created using sns.regplot, with hue deciding the colouring of datapoints at the LOBF plotted based on colour]

Comment: You could try `sns.regplot(...., order=2)` to approximate with a second degree curve. Note that on StackOverflow you are supposed to add reproducible test data (for example one of seaborn's demo datasets, such as `sns.load_dataset('iris')`).   See also [How to apply piecewise linear fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382903/how-to-apply-piecewise-linear-fit-in-python).ç

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to find the knee point and lines automatically, you can fit a curve and then use that information to separate out the steep part from the shallow part. Each of those defines a line, for which you can find the intersection.

The example below shows how to do this for some test data.

[image]

Imports and test data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#
#Make some test data
#
np.random.seed(0)
x0 = np.random.uniform(size=150)
y0 = -1.5 * x0 + 3 + np.random.randn(150) / 7
x1 = 0.8 + np.random.uniform(size=80) * 1.7 / 3
y1 = -0.5 * x1 + 2 + np.random.randn(80) / 13
x2 = 1.5 + np.random.randn(60) / 3
y2 = -0.2 * x2 + 1.6 + np.random.randn(60) / 15

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.concatenate([x0, x1, x2]).tolist(),
    'y': np.concatenate([y0, y1, y2]).tolist(),
    'category': list('A' * len(x0) + 'B' * len(x1) + 'C' * len(x2))
})

# Plot the data
ax = sns.scatterplot(data, x='x', y='y', hue='category')
```

Find two lines and their intersection, and plot.

```py
#Fit an initial quadratic curve to all of the data
poly_fit = np.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(data['x'], data['y'], deg=2)

#Get the curve's values
x_fine = np.linspace(data['x'].min(), data['x'].max(), num=100)
curve = poly_fit(x_fine)
gradient = poly_fit.deriv()(x_fine)

#Since we expect to be fitting a knee in the curve,
# we can incorporate that prior knowledge by
# ignoring the 'upswing' part the curve and re-fitting
# to where the gradients are < shallowest point

#Filter data to points before the gradient minimum
min_pt = x_fine[np.abs(gradient) == np.abs(gradient).min()].item()
x_fine = x_fine[x_fine < min_pt]
data_x = data.loc[data['x'] < min_pt, 'x'].values
data_y = data.loc[data['x'] < min_pt, 'y'].values

#Re-fit curve
poly_fit = np.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(data_x, data_y, deg=2)
curve = poly_fit(x_fine)
gradient = poly_fit.deriv()(x_fine)

#Plot the curve (coloured by gradient)
ax.scatter(x_fine, curve, c=gradient, cmap='Greys_r', zorder=2, s=100, label='curve')
ax.legend()
ax_lims = ax.axis()

#Find 2 lines (a, and b)
# The first line is the average of lower quartile of gradients,
# and the second line is the average of the upper quartile of gradients
slope_a = gradient[gradient < np.quantile(gradient, 0.25)].mean()
slope_b = gradient[gradient > np.quantile(gradient, 0.75)].mean()

#Get an (x, y) point that each line goes through
x0_a, x0_b = [x_fine[np.abs(gradient - slope).argmin()] for slope in [slope_a, slope_b]]
y0_a, y0_b = [poly_fit(x0) for x0 in [x0_a, x0_b]]

#Intercept of each line
# y0 = slope * x0 + intercept -> intercept = y0 - slope * x0
intercept_a = y0_a - slope_a * x0_a
intercept_b = y0_b - slope_b * x0_b

#Final line equations
line_a = slope_a * x_fine + intercept_a
line_b = slope_b * x_fine + intercept_b

#Plot the lines
for label, line, slope, intercept in [('a', line_a, slope_a, intercept_a),
                                      ('b', line_b, slope_b, intercept_b)]:
    ax.plot(
        x_fine, line, color='red', alpha=0.25, linewidth=8,
        label=f'$y_{label}={slope:.2f}x+{intercept:.2f}$'
    )
ax.axis(ax_lims)

#Find their intersection point, and plot
intersect_x = (intercept_b - intercept_a) / (slope_a - slope_b)
intersect_y = slope_a * intersect_x + intercept_a
ax.plot(
    intersect_x, intersect_y, marker='X', color='tab:red', linestyle='none',
    markersize=12, label=f'intersection ({intersect_x:.2f}, {intersect_y:.2f})',
)
ax.legend(fontsize=9)
ax.figure.set_size_inches(8, 4)

#Optionally remove the spines
[ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False) for spine in ['right', 'top']]
```